# Php Permission Issues

Tags: php, linux, github, permissions

I'm facing permission problems.

I have a project for my school lecture which located [here](https://github.com/mert-celen/CinemaProject). It basically download some images from internet. And also It has a setup like wordpress and need to modify some php files.

I have to give 777 permission to img/ and img/Stars/ folders(you can see from github) to download images properly. And setup/index.php,resources/php/functions.php permissions to in order to connect db after modification?)(lol).

So, **is there any way to give those permissions bundled with github so it wont casue any problem, or how can I prevent this permission issues.**

Regards.

Comment: This question is off topic for stack overflow as it is not about a specific programming problem ,but rather a question on linux/unix systems. Please take a look at [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

Can you use chown to set the owner of the necessary scripts to the same user your web server is running as? Possibly _WWW